# Doubt in Dihedral group $D_4$ regarding reflections

Tags: group-theory, self-learning

This question is from Gallian Page 69 Q 9. Suppose a subgroup od D_4 contains H and D. I want to show that these two generated whole of $D_4$. Now rotation will generate other rotations which is fairly clear. But i am confused about how reflections can generate other reflections? Because a reflection say V will, if applied again and again can generate only V and identity which is $R_0$ but how do other reflections can be generated by this

Thanks a lot

Comment: Generated by two elements means that you may compose the two elements as well, so you can consider reflections after a rotation first.

Comment: Hint: multiply reflection with rotations.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Okay In Dihedral group rotation is cyclic means it can be generated by a single rotation. But i think reflection is not cyclic. Please clarify this

Comment: Group elements cannot be cyclic. Please clarify this.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde In Gallian it is written that R denote rotation of 360/n. This generates all rotations. Does it mean that you can multiply R by itself to get all other rotations and what is the reasoning for reflections ?

Comment: Using a physical square made from paper to compose rotations and reflections would be ideal, but if that's inconvenient here's an interactive web page for [exploring $D_{4}$](http://mathcs.holycross.edu/~ahwang/teach/common/software/algebra/D4/navigate.html), where you can do the same with mouse clicks.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang HMM Looks nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dihedral group can be said to have two *generators*. That is you can find two elements of the set of group elements which by iterated operation in different orders can create any other member of the set. Compare to the simpler cyclic group where it is enough with 1 *generating element*. $C_3$ Rotation 120 degrees once, twice and thrice "generates" all three group elements. That makes the set {rotation by 120 degrees} a generating set of size 1 for $C_3$.

For $D_4$ you can pick one particular reflection and say one of the minimal angle rotations and they will together be a generating set. But you may need to build sequences involving both of these generators to generate all elements of the group. You can read more for example here [generating set at Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_set_of_a_group)

Comment: Okay. But you said they will togethor be a generating set. Does it means that a reflection and rotation can be multiplied together with each other as well as individually to generate  Dihedral group

Comment: Yes, see the first and second comment above.

Comment: Ow didn't read them sorry, sorry for any steal. Yes it means you may need to combine them in different orders to generate all elements.